# How do I optimise this numpy array operation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

This numpy operation gives a memory error. (Here X and Y are 2D arrays with shape (5000, 3072) and (500, 3072))

```
dists[:,:] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(X, Y[:,np.newaxis])), axis=2))
```

I think the numpy array broadcasting is taking up a lot of memory. Is there any way to optimise the memory usage for these array operations?

Edit:
(This is a problem in Assignment 1 of cs231n). I found another solution that gives the same thing without a memory error:

```
dists[:,:] = np.sqrt((Y**2).sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] + (X**2).sum(axis=1) - 2 * Y.dot(X.T))
```

Can you help me understand why my solution is inefficient memory wise?

Comment: How big are your arrays?

Comment: X is of shape (5000, 3072) and Y of shape (500, 3072)

Comment: Did you take a look at - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html? Regarding your solution, it's memory inefficient because it bloats up to a huge 3D array with `np.subtract(X, Y[:,np.newaxis])`.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that this is a part of an assignment problem and I am not supposed to use functions from scipy, nor use np.linalg.norm().

Comment: @ArpanBiswas What about your "Edit" code. Does that work for you? Is your problem solved by it?

Comment: The other solution in Edit works for me but I am still trying to optimise my own code to do the job.